# how get the row state of a row in QSqlTableModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.7, qtsql, qsqltablemodel

I have a `QSqlRelationalTableModel`.  I am using `OnManualSubmit` for my edit strategy.  I have called `setTable` and `insertRow`.

Later, how do I know programmatically which rows have been added or edited in the model but have not yet been submitted to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt doesn't expose the list of pending updates, insertion or deletion, you can only check individual indexes with `QSqlTableMode::isDirty`.

But since you have access to the signals `rowsInserted`, `rowsRemoved` and `dataChanged`, you can build these lists yourself.